# Xcode 4/Interface builder layout question: What is the difference between the two?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode4

Picture 1: UIWebView is under View

[image: Picture 1: UIWebView is under View]

Picture 2: UIWebView is at the same level as View

[image: Picture 2: UIWebView is at the same level as Vie]

What is the difference between these two arrangement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, the UIWebView is a subview of the UIView. In the second case, they are siblings (and both top level objects)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Do you know if there is any resource (from apple or not) about the implication of subview vs sibling?

Comment: @Anthony: Have you read the documentation? There's a section in the View Programming Guide that explains exactly this: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy/WorkingWithAViewHierarchy.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH4-SW1